# View execution line in netbeans

Tags: netbeans

How can view the execution line used by netbean v6.8 to execute my java application when I press the run program button (right pointing green arrow)? I'm looking for something like:

java -cp build/class Main

I'm trying to make the jump to java IDE developement from 15 years writing c and c++ with vi. I'm starting with netbean since it seems to have the best vi key bindings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out what I was looking for. Tools->options->Ant tab, where is says 'Verbosity level' set to debug. Then run the application and look for  'Complete build sequence is [run, ]', a few lines down from that is the execute statement, in ant exec format.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug your application, you have to select the option "Debug" and not "Run". In the "debug" option you can set breakpoints and execute the program step by step.

Comment: This isn't what I was asking about.

Comment: Now I see what you want... and you are right, it´s the command line after the build output.