# How to determine which command Netbeans is executing to run the project?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I'm developing an Java application using Netbeans and Maven. I'm struggling a lot to run the project as standalone application. Launching the project from Netbeans is all fine but running the executable jar yields an error (failing to load a data file).

I need to know **exactly** which command(s) Netbeans is executing to run the application. However, the output window of Netbeans only shows me what the application writes "back". Is there a way to figure out/display the command(s) that Netbeans is using to run the project?

Thanks

**EDIT**: Running the java application and loading files is **not** the issue here. I'm able to run the application and the libraries are loading correctly. The issue here is to understand how Netbans runs the application (by looking at the commands that are executed).

Comment: did you create a single jar that contains all data, manifest with which gives Main class using Maven?.  [how to create single jar?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/574650/7584363).

Comment: I did, running a Maven application outside Netbeans is not the issue here. The issue is that I get some error when trying to load a file. However, when I run the application from Netbeans I don't get this error. So i need to figure out **exactly** what commands Netbeans is executing to run the project.

Comment: NetBeans **will** include the Maven command line that it is using in the "Output" window. It's the very first line. But running the generated jar file from the command line will require a completely different command as that is usually not done through maven. Typically that will be something like `java -cp ..... your.main.Class` or (if you provided a manifest) just a `java -jar your.jar`

Comment: Try setting the ["Verbosity" to "Verbose" under Tools > Options > Ant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619046/view-execution-line-in-netbeans).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Netbeans** outputs the command it invokes as the very first line of the output.

I use **Netbeans 8.2** and that's how it looks like when I hit big green **Run** button in `maven` project:

[image: Netbeans Output]

The first line reads (formatted for better readablility):

```
cd D:\test;
"JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_112" 
"M2_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\apache-maven-3.3.3"
cmd /c "\"\"C:\\Program Files\\apache-maven-3.3.3\\bin\\mvn.cmd\"
    -Dexec.args=\"-classpath %classpath com.test.AppStarter\"
    -Dexec.executable=\"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_112\\bin\\java.exe\"
    -Dexec.workingdir=D:\\test\\target\\dist
    -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.2\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\"
    -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
    org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec\""
```

From that line I can tell that **Netbeans**:

- goes to the project's directory
- sets environment variables (`JAVA_HOME` and `M2_HOME`)
- then executes `cmd` that executes `mvn` (by its full path)

  - with bunch of `-D` arguments (which specify working directory and `AppStarter` as a class to execute)
  - and `exec-maven- plugin` with target `exec`.

Answer (score 2):

When **NetBeans** compiles a program it creates a folder-hierarchy with compiled `.class` files. When creating a **JAR** archive **ZIP**s those into the archive. When executing the program, (or debugging,) **NetBeans** runs the `.class` files off the folders, not in the **JAR** file.

These could cause different problems, like different **PATH**. This can cause "file not found" errors with relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

what is your operatingsystem?

**windows:** 
then wmic may be the tool, which could show you the complete commandline. you will find examples here [command line of process by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492997/command-line-of-process-by-name)

**linux:**
try 
    ps -ef | grep java